# Does it make sense to abstract out a separate class to create the value of a cookie in Java?

Tags: java

Say I have a class:

```
public class Foo
{

   // creates a cookie named Session with settings like httpOnly, path, secure etc
}
```

This class also creates the cookie value (creating the value involves some complicated setup)

Does it make sense to have a specific class that has the specific details of the cookies value only, like generating the value without any cookie specific details (httpOnly, secure)?

so basically

```
public class SessionBuilder
{
  // this class holds any value constants or any details on creating the value, without the scope "Cookie" in it
}
```

In my opinion, the second class doesnt make much sense since it's so concrete towards one objective and it'll only ever be used in the `Foo` class. And also, since the `Foo` class is responsible for creating the cookie, I assume it should be responsible for creating the cookie value too.

If it does help to have another class, what name makes sense? `SessionBuilder` sounds a bit weird.

I can see it may be helpful to have another class so in the future if I create more cookies in the `Foo` class, I can abstract out some of the cookie value details in separate classes

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `Foo` class to manage cookies and the value itself, then you may want to have a simple `Session` class to use in order to have more controls on them.

In the end, what does really matter is how you feel more comfortable working with. I'd say it's more a design issue rather than concrete issue, if it was me, i'd simply build the `Cookie` class and then the `Session` class would manage it.

Anyway, **i strongly suggest to use a built-in framework to manage sessions.**
They are really important for web application safety, you may want to look at [SuperTokens.io](https://supertokens.io/)